# Raspberry pi 4 doesn't detect i2c devices

Tags: pi-4, i2c, sensor, raspberry-pi-os

I am working on a gas flow sensor [SFM4100](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/5_Mass_Flow_Meters/Datasheets/Sensirion_Mass_Flow_Meters_SFM4100_Datasheet.pdf). It's communcation protocol is i2c. And according to gasses bus adresses are changing. For o2 gas, address is 2.

[image]

When I connected the all pins according to datasheet , raspberry pi doesn't detect i2c address.
I tried both `sudo i2cdetect -y 0` and `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`

[image]

What is the reason of that ?

Also, my pin [connection](https://pasteboard.co/JTWMPqE.png) .
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the I2C bus in `raspi-config`?

Comment: What is reported by i2cdetect?  Where is the photo clearly showing the connections you have made?

Comment: What are your pullup resistor values?

Comment: Yes, i2c bus enabled. I think that is because of i2c device address. Raspberry pi 4 doesnt detect i2c addresses which are smaller than 3.@PMF

Comment: I didn't use pull up resistor. @ElliotAlderson

Comment: I edited the post @joan

Comment: Actually, I didn't think there is connection error because I tested the sfm4100 o2 sensor in arduino and it worked well. @joan

Comment: Given no device is shown I suggest it is a connection error.  We need a clear photo.

Comment: Okey, I will upload a connection photo and diagram @joan

Comment: [connection](https://pasteboard.co/JTWMPqE.png) is like that @joan

Comment: The photo needs to be added to your question.  The default I2C address of 2 is an illegal address.

Comment: "all pins" - which pins ... exactly

Comment: #noobinmath, datasheet's product section specifies Vcc = 5 ~ 9V. Is there a typo?

Comment: According to the spec, you should connect pin 1 to 5V and pin 3 to 3.3 V ("level shifter voltage" apparently means the _lower_ voltage for the level shifter)

Comment: So, if address 2 is illegal what should I do ? How can ı communicate with this sensor using i2c? @joan

Comment: I edited the question and added the image link of my connection. Thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: Can you not change the address to somewhere in the range 0x03 to 0x77?  If not perhaps you will have to bit bang.  Are you using address 2 with the Arduino code?

Comment: I already connected pin 1 5V and pin 3 3.3V @PMF

Comment: I don't know how can I change the address of sensor @joan but, I tested the sensor in Arduino and used 0x02 as an i2c address. It worked

Comment: Bit bang then. Perhaps experiment with pigs.  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#BI2CO

Comment: Hey @joan ,thank you for your suggestion. I tried many ways  still can't see the i2c device. The link you posted was not very explanatory for me, I have a hard time understanding. Is there a command you specifically suggest me to run?